# Prepend function call in other function in Python

Tags: python, metaprogramming

This is a bit tricky, but what I want, in a simple way, is this:

I have a function `foo` and a decorator `process`

```
@process
def foo(x, y):
    print x + y
```

The decorator is creating a `Process` object, which is handed the `foo` function and it's parameters

```
# The process decorator
def process(func=None, **options):
    if func != None:
        def _call(*args, **kwargs):
            if len(options) > 0 and 'fail' in options:
                return Process(func, fail=options['fail'], *args, **kwargs)
            else:
                return Process(func, fail=None, *args, **kwargs)
        return _call
    else:
        def _func(func):
            return process(func, **options)
        return _func
```

I want to change the `foo` function given to the process-decorator on run-time, to include a call to another function, e.g. a `get_locals()` function, which possibly overwrites the local variables, at the very beginning of `foo`:

```
def foo(x, y):
    get_locals()
    print x + y
```

I've tried to do something with `inspect`, getting the source of the function, and then compiling it into a code object afterwards, however this resulted in a `'code' object is not callable` exception or something similar.

Is this even possible? Are there an easier/better solution?

Comment: func is always going to be not None if used as a decorator? Also `is not None` is the correct way of writing this, as `None` is a singleton.

Comment: This is because the `@process` decorator can have optional arguments, which is also why I check the options array for `'fail'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few different approaches to what you want to do, 
varying in "cleaninness" (as opposed to add-hoc hackish),
easinness to do (and to understand and maintain later),
dependency on Python implementation, and so on.

The limitting factor I see on which approach to use depends on
how you can/want to interfere the declaration of the decorated
function itself.

**1.** So, if you are in a  position
to change all the code that will make use of your decorator
(or document it to others that will use it), the most straightforward,
simpler, and whcih I think I would recomend, way to go, is to re-assign
the function's default argument tuple (foo.func_defaults) at run time.

This approach requires that the variables you want to be overwritten in the running
code be declared as function parameters with default values:

(I will use a simpler decorator than yours for documenting purposes)

```
new_args = (10,20)

def process(func):
    def new_func(*args, **kw):
        func_defaults = func.func_defaults
        func.func_defaults = new_args
        result = func(*args, **kw)
        func.func_defaults = func_defaults
        return result
    return new_func

@process
def foo(x=1, y =2):
    print x + y
```

And that "just works"(tm)

```
>>> foo()
30
```

**2.** Another approach, still requiring the decorated function to follow an specific pattern,
is to declare all variables you want to be overwritten as global variables, and at call time, create a new function object, with everything just equal the original function,
but changing it's globals dictionary. Since you are creating a new function object for each call, this would be thread safe -0 however, you can't change variables that are declared as function  parameters (as Python marks thos as "local", and they can not be subsequently marked as "global")

```
from types import FunctionType

new_args = {"x":10, "y":20} 

def process(func):
    def new_func(*args, **kw):
        temp_func = FunctionType(func.func_code,
                                 new_args,
                                 func.func_name, 
                                 func.func_defaults,
                                 func.func_closure)
        return temp_func(*args, **kw)
    return new_func


@process
def foo():
    global x, y
    print x + y
```

**3.** Following the same approach, for each local variable that you want overriden,
you'd list it at the top of the function as receiving a default value - like
in

```
def foo(x=1,y=2):
   z= 3
   w = 4
```

And at run time you would re-build dinamically at each call, not just the function object,
but its code object as well - Yu could call types.CodeType with teh same parameters as the original func.func_code object, but for the "constants" parameter - which would replace the original's co_consts attributes.

I won't give an example for this way to do things, as it falls in the domain of 
"nice experimental hack, but horrendous for actual production code" - as it is too implementation dependent.

**4.** You can, on your decorator, set code tracing on - which is usually done by debuger utilities, so that you get a call back to a function you specify for each expression to be computed on the target code - 
You could them, enable the "settrace", and in your callback function fiddle with the local variables on the target function.
This is apratnly simple,  once you see the documentation for sys.gettrace - http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.settrace -- however it does hvae the small inconvenient of **not working at all**  :-)
This happens because although you do have right to read and write on the frame locals dictionary, Language optimizations not always fetch values from that dictionary when using them (if ever). 
So this straight forward example shows it not working:

```
>>> import sys
>>> def a():
...    b = 1
...    f = sys._getframe()
...    print f.f_locals
...    f.f_locals["b"] = 2
...    print b
... 
>>> a()
{'b': 1, 'f': <frame object at 0x1038cd0>}
1
```

**5.** Finally, you could do exactly as you say, and use Python's "dis" module and compiler functions to inject variable attribution inside your  function code - directly on the bytecode. You'd have to: decompile the function's code object, successfully meddle with the bytecode to properly load your desired variables with the wanted values, recompile teh byte code, recreate the code object (using teh before mentioned types.CodeType call), passing an appropriate "constants" value to properly load your variables, recreate teh function object from that and make your function call.

I will not enumerate the reasons why I find this approach less useful than others, neither try a reference implementation. It would work, if properly done, though, at least for cpython 2.x.